# Function on a sequence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say $f:R^n \to R$

Under what conditions for $f$ and types of convergence would the following be true:

$x_n$ converges to $x$ iff $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$

Comment: $f$ continuous and injective.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli If f is not injective, how could we ensure the converse remains true?

Comment: No such thing is possible. Being simultaneously continuous and injective is the necessary and sufficient condition for that property to hold for all points and sequences.

Comment: On second thought, it might actually not be sufficient (it is obviously necessary).

Comment: On third though, it is indeed necessary and sufficient.

Comment: It is impossible for a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ to be both continuous and injective, for $n>1$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Oh... In the beginning I was a bit puzzled to hear that the answer was actually "never", but then I realized what the whole question actually means. :)